# My login/ signUp API works fine locally, However when I deploy it it no longer works. I tried it on Postman but it is stuck in sending

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, deployment

Like I said in the question, the code is seamless in my local environment however it aint working in production. I am using mongodb/express__NodeJs Here the major snippets of the code

Server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors');
const router = express.Router()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

require('dotenv').config('./.env')
require('./config/db');

//communication between the front and back end
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))


app.use(express.json())
require('./routes/route')(app,router)

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen({ port},() => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port ${port}`)
})
```

routes

```
module.exports = (app, router) => {
    const userController = require('../controllers/adminControls.js');
    router.use((req,res,next) => {
        next();
    });

    // Routes for Users
            //Adding Users
            app.post('/createUser', userController.addUser);
            //Posting Login Info to Server
            app.post('/login', userController.login);
}
```

Controls.js for most of the logic

```
const User = require('./../models/User')
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
require('dotenv').config('./.env')

//Adding usen
exports.addUser = async (req, res) => {
    let {name, email, password, liscence, latitude, longitude} = req.body;
    name= name.trim()
    email = email.trim()
    password = password.trim()
    liscence = liscence.trim()
    latitude = latitude
    longitude = longitude
    

    if(name == "" || email == "" || password == "" || liscence == ""){
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "empty input fields"
        })
    }else if (!/^[a-zA-Z]*$/.test(name)){
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Invalid name entered"
        }) 
    // }else if (!/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.){2,4}$/.test(email)){
    //     res.json({
    //         status: "FAILED",
    //         message: "Invalid email entered"
    //     }) 
    }else if (password.length < 8){
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "Password is too short"
        }) 
    }else{
        User.find({email}).then(result => {
            if(result.length){
                res.json({
                    status: "FAILED",
                    message: "User already exists"
                }) 
            }else{
                const saltRounds = 10;
                bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds).then(hashedPassword => {
                    const newUser = new User({
                        name,
                        email,
                        password: hashedPassword,
                        liscence,
                        latitude,
                        longitude
                    });
                    newUser.save().then(result=>{
                        res.json({
                            status: "SUCCESS",
                            message: "SIGNUP SUCCESSFUL",
                            data: result
                        }) 
                    })
                }).catch(err => {
                    res.json({
                        status: "FAILED",
                        message: "error occured"
                    }) 
                })
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.json({
                status: "FAILED",
                message: "an Error occured while checking for existing email"
            }) 
        })
    }
};
//Verifying log in information recieved from the front-end
exports.login = async(req, res) => {
    let { email, password} = req.body;
    email = email.trim()
    password = password.trim()
    if(email == "" || password == ""){
        res.json({
            status: "FAILED",
            message: "empty input fields"
        })
    } else{
        User.find({email}).then(data=>{
            if(data){
                const hashedPassword = data[0].password;
                bcrypt.compare(password, hashedPassword).then(result => {
                    if(result){
                        res.json({
                            status: 'Success',
                            message: "Sign in successful",
                            data: data
                        })
                    }else{
                        res.json({
                            status: "FAILED",
                            message: "Password is wrong"
                        })
                    }
                }).catch(err=>{
                    res.json({
                        status: "FAILED",
                        message: "an error occured while comparing passwords"
                    })
                })
            }else{
                res.json({
                    status: "FAILED",
                    message: "invalid credentials"
                })
            }
        }).catch(err=>{
            res.json({
                status: "Failed",
                message: "an error occured while checking for existing email"
            })
        })
    }

}
```

I deployed my code on Render and it is returning no errors. However when I tried using the website deployed on Postman to make changes in Mongodb it became stuck at sending.

I tried rewriting the entire code but I still keep getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had nothing to do with my code.It has been a while since I last worked on this so I am not entirely sure but I think there was something wrong with my database connection when I deployed my server to Heroku.